# How to repeatedly do an event on touch a button

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, touch

I write these codes on touch up inside event of a button , to increase number in the UILabel :

```
int score = [lblScore.text intValue];
score++;
lblScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",score];
```

I want when touch and hold the button , numbers add repeatedly till release button.

Answer (score 1):

touchUp fires, as it says, when your figure is lifted up from the button.

To do this you will need to start a loop inside `touchDown:` and stop it inside `touchUp:`

Comment: loop must be in a timer?

Comment: @nmokkary yes you could use a timer and then invalidate it in the touch up callback